# How can I ignore null headers in a .csv file?

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

How can I ignore null headers in a .csv file?

I have a csv file like this

```
http://190.12.101.70/~digicelc/gestion/reportes/import/liquidacion/13958642917519.csv
```

and my code is

```
data <- read.csv('1.csv',header = T, sep=";")
```

So R tells me

```
  more columns than column names
```

And I don't want to skip the header of the file

thank you!

Comment: Hi, user1532587, and welcome to the site!  Actually, this site is more for statistics questions and not so much for programming questions.  StackOverflow has a lot of R programmers who can answer these questions sometimes better and more quickly than we can, although you may well get an answer here too.

Comment: can you post a link to `1.csv`? there may be something more unique in the file that we're not seeing from the paste

Comment: here's a link
http://190.12.101.70/~digicelc/gestion/reportes/import/liquidacion/13958642917519.csv

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the same behavior here. R adds default column names and NA to unavailable data.

```
> data <- read.csv("test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
> data    
  col1      col2      col3       col4          X X.1
1 val1      val2      val3       val4       val5  NA
2 val1      val2      val3       val4       val5  NA
```

Are you using the latest version?

Comment: this is the actual file
http://190.12.101.70/~digicelc/gestion/reportes/import/liquidacion/13958642917519.csv

Comment: I'm using the actual version, yes

Answer (score 0):

But the error message tells you exactly what the problem is. you have more columns than column names.

```
download.file("http://190.12.101.70/~digicelc/gestion/reportes/import/liquidacion/13958642917519.csv", destfile="1.csv")
D1 <- read.csv2("1.csv", skip=1, header=FALSE)
firstlines <- readLines("1.csv", 3) 
splitthem <- strsplit(firstlines, ";")
sapply(splitthem, length)
# [1] 28 42 42
```

So you have 42 data columns (separated by semicolons) but 28 column names (again, separated by column names). How would R know which name you would want to go with which column? ("Computers are good at following instructions, but not at reading your mind." - Donald Knuth).

You need to edit the source file so that each column would have a name or skip the first row and then get the column names form somewhere else.

#### edit

> *yes, the idea is to take the first names and then standart variables like V1, V2, or*
>   *whatever- Otherwise is there a way to skip those?*

Ok then I would just use the above with slight modification:

```
download.file("http://190.12.101.70/~digicelc/gestion/reportes/import/liquidacion/13958642917519.csv", destfile="1.csv")
D <- read.csv2("1.csv", skip=1, header=FALSE)
header <- strsplit(readLines("1.csv", 3), ";")[[1]]
names(D)[1:length(header)] <- header
```

Now you have the first 28 variables named, and the rest named V29-V42.

You can "skip" the rest of the names in various ways. If you do as suggested in another answer (Dave) , basically as

```
names(D) <- header
```

...  then variables 29-42 will have NA name. This is not a usable name, and you can address these variables only by column number. Or you can do:

```
names(D)[29:43] <- ""
```

Now you can't use these names either.

```
> D[[""]]
NULL
```

I think it is useful to give them names, as many data frame operations presume names. For example, suppose you have empty names ("" as above) and try to see the first few rows of your data frame:

```
head(D)
# skipped most of the output, keeping only column 42:
  structure(c("-1", "70", ".5", "70", "266", "70"), class = "AsIs")
1                                                                -1
2                                                                70
3                                                                .5
4                                                                70
5                                                               266
6                                                                70
```

So when using head, you will see your data frame with funny names. Or another example:

```
D[1:3,29:31]
                             .1                  .2
1 C_COMPONENTE_LIQ_DESDE_CO 243 LIQUIDACION TOPE CO
2 C_COMPONENTE_LIQ_DESDE_CO 243         RESIDUAL CO
3 C_COMPONENTE_LIQ_DESDE_CO 243         RESIDUAL CO
```

- The first component now is named "", the second one ".1", and the third one ".2". Have a look at a quote from data.frame help file below:

> The column names should be non-empty, and attempts to use empty names will have 
>   unsupported results. Duplicate column names are allowed, but you need to use check.names 
>   = FALSE for data.frame to generate such a data frame. However, not all operations on 
>   data frames will preserve duplicated column names: for example matrix-like subsetting 
>   will force column names in the result to be unique.

Or suppose you add some columns to the beginning of your data frame; if you have col names then you can still address what was previously 29th column as D$V29, but with D[,29] you will get something else.

Probably there are other examples. In other words, you can have "unnamed" columns in a data frame but I don't think it is a good idea. And technically, all columns in a data frame  will always have a name (it can just be "" or NA), so why not have meaningful names? (Even V29 is better than nothing.)

Comment: i.e your question is unclear. do you want to name the first 28 columns of data with the names in the first row?

Comment: yes, the idea is to take the first names and then standart variables like V1, V2, or whatever- Otherwise is there a way to skip those?